# opening Self Signed certificate in WebView in android

Tags: android, webview, ssl-certificate

I am trying to open Https SelfSigned certificate website in my webview, But I am facing problem as I am getting SSLConnection error. 
Following is my Code.

```
    URL url;
        String response = "";
        try {
            url = new URL(requestURL);
            HttpURLConnection http;
            if (url.getProtocol().toLowerCase().equals("https")) {
//                conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
//                trustAllHosts();
                HttpsURLConnection https = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
//                https.setHostnameVerifier(DO_NOT_VERIFY);
                http = https;
            } else {
                http = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            }
            http.setReadTimeout(60 * 1000);
            http.setConnectTimeout(60 * 1000);
            http.setRequestMethod("POST");
            http.setDoInput(true);
            http.setDoOutput(true);


            OutputStream os = http.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(getPostDataString(postDataParams));

            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            os.close();
            int responseCode = http.getResponseCode();

            if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                String line;
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(http.getInputStream()));
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    response += line;
                }
            } else {
                response = "";

            }
            Logger.d("Response Result", "performPostCall: " + response);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

How to open it in WebView? I tried

```
@Override
        public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, @NonNull final SslErrorHandler handler,
                                       SslError error) {
handler.proceed();
}
```

But it is not working.
Kindly Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to do certificate pinning?

Comment: @AhmedArnaut actually I am doing payment thingy. So I am getting this SSL error